# Set background color in PHP?

Tags: php, colors

What is the easiest way to set background color in PHP ?

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with background colors. it is dealing with text.

Answer (score 10):

just insert the following line and use any color you like

```
    echo "<body style='background-color:pink'>";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/css');
?>

some selector {
    background-color: <?php echo $my_colour_that_has_been_checked_to_be_a_safe_value; ?>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use CSS. Can't be done with PHP.

Comment: PHP would just change the CSS (or HTML, but that wouldn't be right), not the background color itself...

Comment: I would've given you an upvote, since using CSS is definitely the way to go in this situation, but I'm not really a fan of the sentence *Can't be done*. To sum it up for ion, just use CSS; PHP is the wrong tool for this, unless you have a specific case where it's indispensable, e.g. you have to read the colors from a database.

Answer (score 1):

CSS supports text input for colors (i.e. "black" = #000000 "white" = #ffffff)
So I think the helpful solution we are looking for here is how can one have PHP take the output from an HTML form text input box and have it tell CSS to use this line of text for background color.

So that when a a user types "blue" into the text field titled "what is your favorite color", they are returned a page with a blue background, or whatever color they happen to type in so long as it is recognized by CSS.

I believe Dan is on the right track, but may need to elaborate for use PHP newbies, when I try this I am returned a green screen no matter what is typed in (I even set this up as an elseif to display a white background if no data is entered in the text field, still green?

Answer (score 0):

You can use php in the style sheet. Just remember to set header("Content-type: text/css") in the style.php (or whatever then name is) file

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what you need to do. If you want to set a background colour on a page then you need to use CSS as per Jay's and David Dorward's answers.

If you are building an image with PHP then you can use the GD library to allocate colours yourself. I don't recommend this without thoroughly reading up on how to create images with GD. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  <?php include("bg-color.php") ?>
</style>
```

And bg-color.php can be something like:

```
<?php
//Don't forget to sanitize the input
$colour = $_GET["colour"];
?>
body {
    background-color: #<?php echo $colour ?>;
}
```

Comment: Do you see the comment where it says //Few checks ? By that I ment sanitize the input.

Comment: Although you are right, should have been clear. I apologize if I confused the op.

Comment: look the whole approach is wrong. you cannot actually deal with colors in PHP. you have to determine some TEXT to output and than make PHP output it. But text itself is your choice, not PHP's. You cannot change colors with PHP, you can only output texts. It is HTML/CSS question, not PHP. Not to mention we do not know WHAT background we're working on - a picture, a whole HTML page, a some div.

Comment: well if i can't than i can't, i will just use html color

Answer (score 0):

You better use CSS for that, after all, this is what CSS is for. If you don't want to do that, go with Dorwand's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use css, but php to use to set some class or id for the element, in order to make it generated dynamically.